# Window management in C#

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, window

I am using selenium c# for web automation and I am having a problem arranging windows. See attached image of what am trying to achieve.[image: window tilling]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After a While, I found a workaround.

1. Every time a window is opened I get its handle by

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
 private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
```

and store it.

2. I get the size of the screen by:

```
int h = (int)Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
int w = (int)Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
```

3. I divide the screen and arrange the windows as needed using the function:

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBfpC.jpg)